# Displaying multiple divs based on select tag selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I am trying to achieve is if a user selects a number in the `select` tag, then that many forms should display below the `select` tag. I am using Jquery to achieve this. But it's not working:

Select tag:-

```
<label>How many credit cards do you have:*
    <select name="debts_cards" id="debts_cards" required>
        <option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

The 10 divs containing the same type of form:-

```
<div id="debts_cards_extra">
    <h2>Credit Card 1</h2>
    <label>
        Provider:
        <input type="text" name="debts_cards_extra_provider">
    </label>
    <label>
        Credit Card Limit:
        <input type="number" name="debts_cards_extra_limit">
    </label>
    <label>
        How much do you have owing:
        <input type="number" name="debts_cards_extra_owing">
    </label>
</div>
<div id="debts_cards_extra2">
    <h2>Credit Card 2</h2>
    <label>
        Provider:
        <input type="text" name="debts_cards_extra2_provider">
    </label>
    <label>
        Credit Card Limit:
        <input type="number" name="debts_cards_extra2_limit">
    </label>
    <label>
        How much do you have owing:
        <input type="number" name="debts_cards_extra2_owing">
    </label>
</div>
<div id="debts_cards_extra3">
    <h2>Credit Card 3</h2>
    <label>
        Provider:
        <input type="text" name="debts_cards_extra3_provider">
    </label>
    <label>
        Credit Card Limit:
        <input type="number" name="debts_cards_extra3_limit">
    </label>
    <label>
        How much do you have owing:
        <input type="number" name="debts_cards_extra3_owing">
    </label>
</div>
<!-- and so on..... -->
```

Jquery:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#debts_cards').on('change', function() {
  if ( this.value == '0' )
  //.....................^.......
  {
    $("#debts_cards_extra").hide();
  }
  elseif ( this.value == '1' )
  {
    $("#debts_cards_extra").show();
  }
  elseif ( this.value == '2' )
  {
    $("#debts_cards_extra").show();
    $("#debts_cards_extra2").show();
  }
  elseif ( this.value == '3' )
  {
    $("#debts_cards_extra").show();
    $("#debts_cards_extra2").show();
    $("#debts_cards_extra3").show();
  }
  elseif ( this.value == '4' )
  {
    $("#debts_cards_extra").show();
    $("#debts_cards_extra2").show();
    $("#debts_cards_extra3").show();
    $("#debts_cards_extra4").show();
  }
// and so on.....
});
});
```

Why is it not working?
Here you can see it [live](http://testwebsitepage.club/application/).
Please note that I am working on Wordpress.
Any help in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the live demo, All 10 divs are shown when the page is first loaded.

So the `$("#debts_cards_extra").show();` wont make any difference because the divs are already visible in the first place.

For every divs you can do `style = "display:none;"`:

```
<div id="debts_cards_extra" style = "display:none;">
    <h2>Credit Card 1</h2>
    <label>
        Provider:
        <input type="text" name="debts_cards_extra_provider">
    </label>
    <label>
        Credit Card Limit:
        <input type="number" name="debts_cards_extra_limit">
    </label>
    <label>
        How much do you have owing:
        <input type="number" name="debts_cards_extra_owing">
    </label>
</div>
```

**EDIT:: I changed the `elseif` to `if` in [This](https://jsfiddle.net/sijanbhattarai/gk9561m0/) fiddle. It Worked.**

Answer (score 0):

you missed the id instead of

```
 <select name="debts_cards" required>
```

use

```
<select id="debts_cards" required>
```

also change:

```
this.value to $(this).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

`<select name="debts_cards" required>` replace   `<select name="debts_cards" id='debts_cards' required>`

take select value in one variable `var selectedValue=$('#debts_cards').val()` and replace this.value to `selectedValue`

Comment: I just did that as Antonio Pangallo pointed it out but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: <input type="text" name="debts_cards_extra_provider"> then in jquery it should be  $(".debts_cards_extra_provider").show();

Comment: if you put id in html then only use #, if you put name then in jquery put .

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
ABC();
});

function ABC(){  
var sleectedValue=$('#debts_cards').val();
  if (sleectedValue == '0' )
  //.....................^.......
  {
    $("#debts_cards_extra").hide();
  }
  else if (sleectedValue == '1' )
  {
    $("#debts_cards_extra").show();
  }
  else if (sleectedValue == '2' )
  {
    $("#debts_cards_extra").show();
    $("#debts_cards_extra2").show();
  }
  else if (sleectedValue == '3' )
  {
    $("#debts_cards_extra").show();
    $("#debts_cards_extra2").show();
    $("#debts_cards_extra3").show();
  }
  else if (sleectedValue == '4' )
  {
    $("#debts_cards_extra").show();
    $("#debts_cards_extra2").show();
    $("#debts_cards_extra3").show();
    $("#debts_cards_extra4").show();
  }
// and so on.....
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>How many credit cards do you have:*
    <select name="debts_cards" id="debts_cards" onchange="ABC();" required>
        <option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
</label>

<div id="debts_cards_extra">
    <h2>Credit Card 1</h2>
    <label>
        Provider:
        <input type="text" name="debts_cards_extra_provider">
    </label>
    <label>
        Credit Card Limit:
        <input type="number" name="debts_cards_extra_limit">
    </label>
    <label>
        How much do you have owing:
        <input type="number" name="debts_cards_extra_owing">
    </label>
</div>
<div id="debts_cards_extra2">
    <h2>Credit Card 2</h2>
    <label>
        Provider:
        <input type="text" name="debts_cards_extra2_provider">
    </label>
    <label>
        Credit Card Limit:
        <input type="number" name="debts_cards_extra2_limit">
    </label>
    <label>
        How much do you have owing:
        <input type="number" name="debts_cards_extra2_owing">
    </label>
</div>
<div id="debts_cards_extra3">
    <h2>Credit Card 3</h2>
    <label>
        Provider:
        <input type="text" name="debts_cards_extra3_provider">
    </label>
    <label>
        Credit Card Limit:
        <input type="number" name="debts_cards_extra3_limit">
    </label>
    <label>
        How much do you have owing:
        <input type="number" name="debts_cards_extra3_owing">
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, typing out or copy-pasting all of the repeated HTML is a really poor technique when they all follow some kind of format. It's better if for you to generate/remove the HTML `onchange`.

Also a `form` is probably better than a div since they are somewhat like a form, and it would probably be easier to target them.

```js
var credit_card_form = `
    <label>
        Provider:
        <input type="text" name="debts_cards_extra_provider">
    </label>
    <label>
        Credit Card Limit:
        <input type="number" name="debts_cards_extra_limit">
    </label>
    <label>
        How much do you have owing:
        <input type="number" name="debts_cards_extra_owing">
    </label>
`;

function formGenerator (event) {
  let quantity = event.target.value
  let forms = $("form")
  
  console.log(forms.length, quantity)
  
  if (forms.length > quantity) {
    forms.slice(quantity).each( function(index) {
      $(this).remove()
    })
  }
  
  if (forms.length < quantity) {
    for (let i = forms.length; i < quantity; i++) {
      let new_form = document.createElement("form");
      new_form.name = "debts_cards_extra"
      let num = i + 1
      let title = `<h2>Credit Card ${num}</h2>`
      new_form.innerHTML = title + credit_card_form
      $(".body").append(new_form);
    }
  }
  
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="body">

<label>How many credit cards do you have:*
    <select name="debts_cards" id="debts_cards" onchange="formGenerator(event)" required>
        <option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
</label>

</div>
```